# Why isn't my New() firing?

Tags: c#

I'm having problems with the code below.  Whenever I create a new instance of the class below and call "Select" I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object on the "this.db"

```
namespace SPI {

    class CompaniesDB
    {
        private DataContainer db;

        public void New() {
            this.db = new DataContainer();
        }
        public Company Select(int companyID) {
            return this.db.Company_Get(companyID).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone point me at why my "New()" doesn't seem to be creating a new object?

I'm relatively new to C#.

Comment: Have you tried it without the "this." prefix?  I am not entirely sure that you need it since it is declared as a class variable.  Also, when you declare a spi.CompaniesDB variable, are you using the New() declaration?  (VB Equivalent example) Dim myDB as companiesDB = new CompaniesDB().  Just 2 cents.

Comment: @Tommy - Mike's issue has nothing to do with using the `this` reference. See @Moron's answer.

Comment: @Tommy: No the `this.` specifyer is not needed, but it makes no difference if it's there or not as there is nothing else in the scope named `db`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't name a constructor as `New`. You name it with the class Name.

Try

```
namespace SPI { 

    class CompaniesDB 
    { 
        private DataContainer db; 

        public CompaniesDB() { 
            this.db = new DataContainer(); 
        } 
        public Company Select(int companyID) { 
            return this.db.Company_Get(companyID).SingleOrDefault(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

MSDN page on constructors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx

Comment: It shouldn't have a return type, either.

Comment: Or you could assign a new instance of DataContainer to db upon declaration of the variable.

Comment: @fle: Yes, but the question (IMO) is more about constructors than how to initialize data members.

Comment: It would stop the null reference exception he was experiencing

Comment: @Moron: +1, but please dont post old links

Comment: @John: Thanks for editing. Will try to keep your suggestion in mind next time. (Though any link we post will soon get old :-))

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Still trying to get used to the differences in VB & C#

Comment: @flet: The problem is more fundamental. Besides, having the constructor defined correctly also solves the NullReference problem.

Comment: @Moron: MSDN links without the version number will always point to the most recent released version.

Comment: I agree that it is important that OP understands the purpose of a constructor, but I also believe it is beneficial that he understands that a constructor is not entirely necessary in this situation. After all, we are trying to share what we know to help others get better.

Comment: @flet: It is not about what might be beneficial to OP. It is about what the question is asking. Going off on a tangent is usually considered noise on StackOverflow.

Comment: @fletcher I'd love your feedback on the issue of the constructor.  The only reasons I initiate it there is 1. I always have, and 2. every sub/function in the class uses that datacontainer so it keeps me from having to create that initialization code in every one.  Feedback appreciated.

Comment: @Mike Jolley - I have edited my post with further information. It is correct to create your DataContainer instance upon creation of the CompaniesDB object, if it is never going to change. There are two ways to do this, hopefully my edit explains what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the New method to CompaniesDB? Also remove the 'void' modifier.

Comment: Knew it had to be something super simple.  Trying to get past the differences with VB.

Answer (score 1):

Do you intend for New() to be your constructor? If so, the syntax for constructors in C# asks for the name of the class. So your constructor should be something like:

```
public CompaniesDB()
{
    this.db = new DataContainer();
}
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the DataContainer constructor requires no arguments and instantion isn't affected by a variable within your New function, therefore you could do away with that function entirely. You could instantiate the DataContainer upon declaration of the private db variable:

```
namespace SPI {

    class CompaniesDB
    {
        private DataContainer db = new DataContainer();

        public Company Select(int companyID) {
            return this.db.Company_Get(companyID).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit, further information as per Mike Jolley's request:

This is really down to preference, both solutions will work and are safe.

You could use the following code:

```
namespace SPI { 

    class CompaniesDB 
    { 
        private DataContainer db;

        public CompaniesDB()
        {
            db = new DataContainer();
        }

        public Company Select(int companyID) { 
            return this.db.Company_Get(companyID).SingleOrDefault(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

This code is good, you are creating an instance of DataContainer whose reference will be assigned to the db variable. You are ensuring that the db variable contains a reference when you want to start using it.

However, this instantiation is always the same, therefore you could get rid of the assignment within the constructor and just create a normal DataContainer by default. This would also ensure that the variable always contains a reference to a DataContainer upon instantiation of a CompaniesDB object:

```
namespace SPI { 

    class CompaniesDB 
    { 
        private DataContainer db = new DataContainer(); 

        public Company Select(int companyID) { 
            return this.db.Company_Get(companyID).SingleOrDefault(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The need for a constructor would be clear if the DataContainer constructor took an argument:

```
namespace SPI { 

    class CompaniesDB 
    { 
        private DataContainer db;

        public CompaniesDB(string name)
        {
            db = new DataContainer(name);
        }

        public Company Select(int companyID) { 
            return this.db.Company_Get(companyID).SingleOrDefault(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The introduction of an argument would mean that it would be better to create the instance of DataContainer in the constructor.

Comment: +1: One could argue that we don't need constructors in a well designed program :-)